# args[0] = numbers. How to do this?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a command  i want that user to be able to write only numbers, not words (!flip test ...) how to write this correctly? I’ll do it myself later, if the user wrote a text in 1 argument, the bot will answer him: You can’t put it, write the number

My code here:

```
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, You forgot to write a bet!`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if `args[0]` is not a number `isNaN()`

```js
if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply('you need to enter a number!')
```